# classic asp SetLocale number formats

Tags: asp-classic, localization

I have a site that had SetLocale(1033) [english united states] however I now had to change it to Chinese SetLocale(2052). That works great in that monthname etc returns Chinese, however my number format has gone to town. Instead of 0.33 the results are .33 for example and code crashes. I think that the date format has also changed.

This is an issue as there is a LOT of code that will need to be edited accordingly. Is there a way to setLocale to Chinese but keep other format as per United States?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You set the locale, what did you expect?

Comment: OK.  Then how do I allow the site to return the Chinese for monthname but still retain other formatting?

Comment: You don't, formatting is just that. If the code crashes you have a bigger problem, you should never be performing computations with formatted values they are purely for display, this goes for Dates, Numbers etc. Any code should work with the raw values then be formatted when displayed. Formatting is always returned as a string, no computations should ever use a string.

Comment: you are 100% right. unfortunately we have inherited this Goliath of code (it is being rewritten). It needs to show Chinese names for days (Monday, Tuesday etc. ) as well as names of months. but the format has been handled badly for dates and numbers. Was hoping to be able to set the language as chinese but the numbers and dates as usa. i.e. if there was a way to overwrite the dates and number format, or just set the language and keep everything the same. The new rewrite will do a better job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Session.LCID to capture your formatted information then set it back to normal at the end of processing.

```
oldsession = Session.LCID
Session.LCID = 2057
day_uk = WeekdayName(3)
Session.LCID = 1036
day_fr = WeekdayName(3)
Session.LCID = 1034
day_es = WeekdayName(3)
Session.LCID = oldsession
response.write day_uk & " | " & day_fr & " | " & day_es
```

I used UK English, French and Spanish locales as the Chinese was not loaded on my server.